# Windows Event log file

Tags: java

I have a program which reads a file every time and now I want to read the event log file of windows ,how can I get the location and read its contents.

The logs are stored in the **%SystemRoot%\System32\Config** directory with a .evt extension. Within the Computer Manager you can also export them to a .txt or .csv file.

Windows Vista/7/Server2008 location, here it is: **%SystemRoot%\system32\winevt\logs**

**My Code is:**

```
String fileSeperator = File.separator;
String filePath = "C:" + fileSeperator + "WINDOWS" + fileSeperator + "system32" + fileSeperator + "winevent" + fileSeperator + "logs";
System.out.println("FilePath :" + filePath);
File f = new File(filePath);
System.out.println("Is Directory :" + f.isDirectory());
```

**The Output:**

FilePath : `C:\WINDOWS\system32\winevent\logs`

Is Directory :false

Why does it return it is not a directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the file doesn't exist. You said yourself that the location was `%SystemRoot%\system32\winevt\logs`. Yet you use `C:\WINDOWS\system32\winevent\logs`.

`winevt != winevent`.

Comment: yes .I changed the path as String filePath = "C:" + fileSeperator + "WINDOWS" + fileSeperator + "system32" + fileSeperator + "config";  and it works